# Simple single ruby file web app

Tags: php, javascript, ruby, webserver

Okay this seems like a real noob question.

I currently have a simple html and javascript news reader running on my MAMP server. You can see it on [Github](https://github.com/laverboy/message-mobile). Everything runs client side except for fetching and caching the feeds which is done by a really small php file. I have an ajax call which requests the news feed from the php script by passing some parameters to it.

I have of late been learning Ruby and have started to redo this simple php script in Ruby. The problem I have is that I can't just request the ruby script via ajax with parameters like I would do with php.

So what would be the simplest steps to take to be able to do this?

I feel like a full blown framework, even as small as Sinatra, would be overkill. So any help would be much appreciated. Am I completely thinking about this the wrong way round? Thanks.

**Update**

I went the Ruby CGI way in the end. Here's what I did.

In the folder I had my script I added a .htaccess file with the following to make apache execute the .rb file.

```
AddHandler cgi-script .rb
Options +ExecCGI
```

Then I started my ruby file off like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'cgi'

cgi = CGI.new('html4')

cgi.out {
    cgi.html {
        "Hello World" #started content here   
    }

}
```

I then made sure the file was executable. `chmod 774`.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution here would be [Ruby CGI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html).

Comment: I think using Rack is easier than pure Ruby CGI. Is it easy to setup server with Ruby CGI?

Comment: Do you already have a webserver configured?  I'm guessing you do since you have PHP running (perhaps with apache and mod_php)?  If that's the case, setting it up to handle Ruby CGI is easy.

Comment: thanks guys, this was the way I went in the end. The missing piece of the puzzle though was adding .htaccess rules to recognise rb files and making the file executable.

Answer (score 0):

If you think sinatra is still big for you, go deeper and try to write pure Rack app.

For example see this minimal app - https://github.com/stevenwilkin/ip.stevenwilkin.com

Rack needs only 3 elements array like this

```
[200           , {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, [env["REMOTE_ADDR"]]]
[return status , headers hash                    , body string         ]
```

Rails, Sinatra and a lot of another ruby web frameworks are using Rack inside.

And if you need request params nicely formated, you can just use http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Request.html for example.

Comment: so do you have to run it in it's own server like the app you pointed to?

Comment: You can use any app server rack is supported by.
https://github.com/rack/rack#supported-web-servers